# how can I validate column names and count in an List array? C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'm trying to get this resolved in .NET 2.0 and unfortunately that is not negotiable.

I am reading in a csv file with columns of data that 'should' correspond to a List of tickers in IdentA with some modifications.
The csv file columsn would read:

```
A_MSFT,A_CSCO,_A_YHOO,B_MSFT,B_CSCO,B_YHOO,C_MSFT,C_CSCO,C_YHOO

IdentA[0]="MSFT"<br>
IdentA[1]="CSCO"<br>
IdentA[2]="YHOO"<br>

The AssetsA array is populated with the csv data<br>
AssetsA[0]=0<br>
AssetsA[1]=1.1<br>
AssetsA[2]=0<br>
AssetsA[3]=2<br>
AssetsA[4]=3.2<br>
AssetsA[5]=12<br>
AssetsA[6]=54<br>
AssetsA[7]=13<br>
AssetsA[8]=0.2<br>
```

The C_ columns are optional but if they exist they all need to exist.  All of the suffixes must match the values in IdentA.  The values in the csv files all need to be decimal.
I'm using a group of 3 as an example, there could be any number of tickers in the IdentA array.

Its easy enough to do the first part:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < IdentA.Count; x++)
    {
        decimal.TryParse(AssetsA[x + IdentA.Count], out currentelections);
    }
```

So that will get me the first set of values for the A_ columns but how can I get through B_ and C_ ?  I can't do something as simple as IdentA.Count*2...

**EDIT:** IdentA gets populated when the first line of the csv is read, AssetsA is populated on subsequent lines until EOF.  The original designer just always assumed that B_ and C_ would always exist and the data would just 'fall into place'.  Going to look at what it would take to redesign it :(

Comment: Could I suggest that you are probably using the wrong data structure if I am reading your problem correctly.  I would suggest a map of {string,ArrayList}.  In the map, read each ident column as a KEY, then when filling assets, it would be myMap["A_MSFT"].Add(value).  Much cleaner design and will make your current problem much easier to resolve.

Comment: I like that idea but I'm trying to work this under the context of existing code that works 95% of the time.  Heck, nobody even knew it was a problem for 2yrs until someone left off the C_ data entirely and then the existing IdentA.Count*2 test broke.  I might just reach for the filet knife and gut it but it isn't my first option if I could avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use 2d arrays to go through two arrays like so

```
for(int i = 0; i <= twoDeeArr[0].Count-1; i++)
{
     for(int j = 0; j <= twoDeeArr.Count-1; j++)
     {
          decimal.TryParse((decimal)twoDeeArr[i][j], out currentElections);
     }
}
```